# Router that would connect to 2 ISPs and mobile hotspot to provide quality service?

Tags: router

I'm based in London.

I can have two independent fibers delivered to my door *(roughly £30 per month each)* + unlimited 4G LTE *(£25 per month)*

I would like to find router that would **connect to 3 independent uplinks** and provide superior speeds.

*(normally a single fiber would be sufficient but due to "engineering works" speeds are    and I'm constantly thinking how to make them better)*

I don't even know if this is possible. I assume my use case is not frequent for home users, business users must been doing it for ages...

Comment: I THINK what you're thinking of is called multihoming

Comment: What you're describing is connection-level load balancing.  It won't speed up individual data transfers, but will let you do more simultaneous transfers without slowing things down.  Combining the uplinks into a single "virtual" connection will speed up individual transfers, but can only be done with multiple uplinks from a single ISP, since the hardware at the other end of the uplinks needs to cooperate with you.

Comment: @Mark Now I understand why load balancing comes to mind.

Comment: Multihoming, that's the word. Now, what router will do all the heavy lifting for me? (plug and play)

Answer (score 1):

So what you are after is an internet bonding device. [Here is a great blog post about it, with video.](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/660357-itel-bonded-internet/)

You will have to talk to your ISP to see about acquiring a bonding device, because they will be splitting all traffic to/from you house into 2 separate pipes. It's quite interesting how it works, and according to linus tech tips it works almost flawlessly when the ISP is involved.

The solution above will work with the two fiber connections, not with the 3g/4g connection.

There are software solutions that will let you blend multiple speeds from multiple providers, however none of them will actually give you the speed increase you a looking for.

[This ZyXel router](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833181137&cm_re=duel_wan-_-33-181-137-_-Product) Supports duel wan connections, allowing you to prioritize your traffic. This would allow you to have certain people on a certain connection... but it does not actually bond the speeds  together giving you any actual speed increase. It just gives you better performance over a larger set of people. Also provides fail safe in case one ISP is going through an outage. Actual bonding, where traffic is split between two separate pipes and reassembled in you home is done at the ISP level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service in the UK called SharedBand, but this is proprietary and I think I am correct in saying that you would have to have the two lines directly from the same company.

This could be used in conjunction with your 4G data connection by using both an ethernet connection from your two SharedBand routers and a wireless connection from your 4G mobile data connection. Your join the two with Windows adapter bridging mode if that works for you.

MacOS and Linux may have something similar but I'm not sure about it.

Edit, we had this at my business premises because we were right out in the middle of nowhere and it was awfully slow. had this put in, almost a 1.8x speed increase, so with fibre, you are laughing with that kind of boost. particularly if both lines run at 76mbps and 4G on top of that.

You might want to check if your computer's adaptor has the ability to go faster than 100mbps if you are using those kind of speeds though.